# Is there a good tool for Eclipse to edit SWT interface graphically (WYSIWYG)?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, editor, wysiwyg

I develop features for Eclipse, and I often have to make SWT GUIs, for ex. Wizards. Coding SWT in Java isn't difficult to me, but I would like sometimes to see in real time what I get. Actually, I found some extensions for Eclipse to edit SWT graphically, but I want to know some other users' experiences in that area, to decide if is it worth to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the **WindowBuilder** (https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

It has a plugin for Eclipse and works with SWT and Swing.

Comment: I have just installed it. I will check it out.